# Does anyone know the name of this typography/design style?

Tags: fonts, typography, style-identification

[image: Type of typography/design]

Does anyone know of a label that could be applied to the style of typography/design above?

Comment: Do you mean, what *style* is it in? I'd call it "80's"

Comment: Hi Sam, if you're looking for the name of this style, please [edit] your question and re-tag it as [style-identification]. If you'd like to identify the font, check out our [requirements for font identification questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions)

Comment: Thanks @JohnB though I'm sure it's probably not a font and more of a design style that I'm looking for... I'm not sure how I could be more specific as it's a very straight forward question.

Comment: @Sam it's worded confusingly, though. What do you mean by 'type' of design? For 'type' I'd say it's just words set in type. There's nothing special about it. For 'style' you could use terms like 'geometric', '80s modern' or even 'sorta art deco'. But there's no 'one' term for this.

Comment: Seems like OP makes a mistakes / confuses typography (a define set of characters) and "lettering" (custom letters drawn one by one by an artist).
The "graphical style" is a mix of 80s shapes with modern colors, the letters are in different styles each, ranging from "deco", "art nouveau" "skewed" and "geometric".

Answer (score 5):

This is drawing heavily from [The Memphis Group's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memphis_Group) design motifs. They became shorthand for the 80s, due to the rather bizarre level of market acceptance they received during that period.

[image]

For something slightly less gaudy, also look at [Constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(art)) and [De Stijl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Stijl).

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably call it '80s revival' as the colours, while still gaudy, are slightly more muted than actual 1980s colours (for example, 'Miami Vice' titles or The Memphis Group's furniture, as @plainclothes says).

If you want a shorter term, how about 'naff'!? (If you lived through the 80s it's quite depressing to see this sort of mish-mash come back on behance, etc.)